# PHP: Serves blank page on webserver (error 500), but works fine on local (Smarty template engine)

Tags: php, html, apache, server, smarty

I have a website that is built with Smarty 3 template engine in PHP 7, and when uploading it to the web server (Apache), it serves a blank page instead of the constructed html. The website works 100% perfect in the local environment, but the server seems to not like something going on.

The output I get when using,

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL + E_NOTICE);
echo('<br>PHP version:' . phpversion());
```

is,

> **PHP version:** `5.2.9`
>
> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined function `spl_autoload_register()` in `/www/mydomain.com/html/assets/inc/vendor/smarty/Autoloader.php` on line 81

Now I am positive that the two different versions of PHP aren't causing this issue, as I have uploaded and run other `.php` files to the server in the past (PHP 7 as well), and they display fine to the client.

What I am not understanding is how the `spl_autoload_register()` function is not defined because the function is definitely there on line 81 of `Autoloader.php`, and it's not like it isn't available to the version of PHP running on the webserver ([see the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)).

Is it maybe the `/html` path?. The `/html` directory on the webserver is where the `index.*` file goes along with all the other pages and their assets, so I am not putting them in the wrong spot... but why is the path going from `/www/mydomain.com` into `/html`, shouldn't it be going right into `/assets`?

Really hope this made sense, thank you in advance!

Comment: apt-get upgrade (:

Comment: Your server has PHP 5.2 installed

Comment: @num8er Does that have to done via CLI? I currently don't have access to anything else other than an FTP login.  
@CharlotteDunois Yes, I am aware of that. But the docs says that versions 5 - 7 are fine. Unless, what they mean by `PHP 5 >= 5.1.2, PHP 7` is that anything between 5.1.2 and 7 __doesn't__ have access to the `spl_autoload_register()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Call to undefined function spl_autoload_register()

do it in index.php file:

```
<?php phpinfo(); die;
```

You'll see that `SPL` extension does not exist.

Maybe SPL extension not installed when was compiled from sources.

Just install new version of PHP (better 5.6) and problem will disappear.

or better upgrade Your packages:

Debian, Ubuntu and etc deb based:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Arch, Gentoo and etc:

```
pacman -Syu
```

I'm Arch Linux user and have no problems with fresh stuff. (:

p.s. at last switch to normal web server or at least DigitalOcean droplet, AWS EC2 instance and etc to have full control on server and libs.

Also You can replace `spl_autoload_register` with replacement.

create a file called `spl_autoload_register.php` in relative folder and put this code:

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('spl_autoload_register')):
    $_spl_autoloaders = array();

    /**
     * Autoloader compatibility callback.
     */
    function __autoload($classname)
    {
        global $_spl_autoloaders;
        foreach ($_spl_autoloaders as $autoloader) {
            if (!is_callable($autoloader)) {
                continue;
            }

            call_user_func($autoloader, $classname);

            if (class_exists($classname, false)) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register a function to be autoloaded.
     */
    function spl_autoload_register($autoload_function, $throw = true, $prepend = false) {
        if ($throw && !is_callable($autoload_function)) {
            throw new Exception('Function not callable');
        }

        global $_spl_autoloaders;

        if (in_array($autoload_function, $_spl_autoloaders)) {
            return;
        }

        if ($prepend) {
            array_unshift($_spl_autoloaders, $autoload_function);
            return;
        }

        $_spl_autoloaders[] = $autoload_function;
    }

    /**
     * Unregister an autoloader function.
     */
    function spl_autoload_unregister($function) {
        global $_spl_autoloaders;

        foreach ($_spl_autoloaders as &$autoloader) {
            if ($autoloader === $function) {
                unset($autoloader);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the registered autoloader functions.
     */
    function spl_autoload_functions() {
        return $GLOBALS['_spl_autoloaders'];
    }
endif;
```

and then in top of main file of Your app require it:

```
require_once 'spl_autoload_register.php';
```

this code will replace missing `spl_autoload_register` function with custom one that works identically same.

Comment: cli php and web php may not be the same

Comment: @num8er To clarify, you're saying to put `phpinfo(); die;` into my index.php? That will then tell me that `SPL` doesn't exist?

I currently only have access to an FTP login, so I am not sure if updating the dependencies is possible for me since I don't have access to the servers' browser interface, or CLI (I am pretty sure that it is the PHP versions clashing after reading the comments and your post).

Comment: phpinfo gives all info about installed php module that serves web requests, You'll see list of extensions that enabled and I think that PHP 5.2.9 does not mean that SPL must exist by default, because it can be compiled from sources where SPL is disabled. Better contact hosting provider, or find a way to replace spl_autoload_register with custom written script.

Comment: @mcjordalini I've updated my answer and put missing spl_autoload_register code in php, just create file, put code and include on top of Your app before everything.

Comment: @num8er Thank you very much for the insight. I will apply what you have told me and see where it gets me, thanks!

Comment: @num8er Thanks a lot for taking the time to write/ find that `spl_autoload_register` script :) I will mark your answer as correct when I get a chance to implement the suggested fixes if they workout!

Comment: @mcjordalini this replacement is copied from wordpress core files https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/compat.php?rev=37637 (;